# What does "ext" mean, as referred to by the sfntly installation instructions?

Tags: install-from-source

This should be an easy one. I'm following [these](http://code.google.com/p/sfntly/wiki/build_cpp) instructions to install [sfntly](http://code.google.com/p/sfntly/). The instructions for installing a package say that the package should be "extracted to ext". What is meant by "ext"? Is this a directory? (I don't see a directory called "ext" in the root.)

Comment: those are very short instructions... can you post the entire thing or link to the place with instructions of the 'package'. Also, are you talking about a regular compressed tar archive or .deb package? This could mean 'extract to any directory which I just happen to call ext', or anything else depending on the context...

Comment: No problem. I updated the question with a link to the full instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand in the instructions, the main package `sfntly` needs the Google C++ testing framework. They say you should extract the latter to `ext`, probably meaning that the source of the main package has a directory `ext` where you should place the Google C++ testing framework and rename it to `gtest` (or make a link).

So, if the `sfntly` source has a directory `ext`, that is where you should put e.g. the Google C++ testing framework (the name suggests it is where you should put external library software).

Comment: Yeah, I'm an idiot :-) Indeed, the sfntly package has an 'ext' directory. I get it now! I though it was something cryptic...